# Create an EJB that can't be instantiated with NEW

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

So for a basic EJB

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class boo {
...
}
```

This project is converting a massive business logic jar that was written 10 years ago using a static method pattern into an EJB pattern and REST services.  My problem is the example above is instantiated in potentially hundreds of places like this

```
boo = new boo();
```

this is making my life miserable.  Since EJB won't let you do a private constructor, is there a way that i can have the use of the NEW statement cause a compiler error so we make my life easier tracking down everything and converting them into bean injections?  I have one class that's instantiated in 773 places.

Comment: And if you create another constructor with parameters and delete the default empty constructor? It will show where new boo() is happening, right?! And use cdi @Inject in the object declaration

Comment: Thats sorta what we are doing now.  My problem is half our dev team is offshore and we have found a few of them using new after being told not to.  I can't think of a pattern that would prevent that going forward.  But sure, during coding we can create bogus constructors and such and delete them and move to the next class and so on.

Comment: Ok, i understod. Maybe it is an idea using some factory pattern to prevent 'new' usage, but this way i don't think it will be possible to use EJB

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to *temporarily* make it private to help find compilation errors.

Also, there are tools in most IDEs that will allow you to "find usages" or "find references". Simply create the public no-args constructor, then right-click on the constructor name, then select the find command. On Eclipse, it is simply called "References".

Answer (score 0):

One another way is to,

place cursor on the `public constructor` in eclispe, and press `Ctrl+Shift+G`, it will find the usage of the `constructor` (reference) across the `project`.